# Connect to VGA console via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, hdmi, tmux

I have Rock Pi which has HDMI output. Normally I see its console on connected monitor. I can also connect via SSH to this Pi.

But I am looking for a way to SSH into this Pi and switch the view to the VGA output console (DISPLAY), so I would operate from my PC on the monitor connected to Pi.

Is it possible, if yes - how? Can I do something like that without `screen` or `tmux`?

No direct keyboard or mouse is available for this Pi. Also session should be interactive and possible to abandon (it would stay on the monitor without SSH connection).

EDIT: What about Xming?

Comment: Use X forwarding?

Comment: @davidgo There is no X.

Comment: Are you sure you mean VGA then, and not tty . console?

Comment: @davidgo I need to see and interact with what is on the main screen visible on the monitor connected via HDMI.

Comment: What about Xming?

Comment: There is a thing called smoething like an X server which I think people are talking about and SSH can connect to that. But really SSH is the wrong program for what you are looking to do. You are looking for a program like VNC..  (VNC can be tunneled through SSH but there are limits re performance of protocols with a lot of data transfer, tunneled through SSH). Many will use VNC with a VPN.  SSH with X server isn't quite equivalent to VNC.

Comment: @barlop I know VNC and other similar. The main thing is I need to connect to monitor output - the same console screen. Maybe it is tty0 or sth similar.

Comment: @pbies hmm does each monitor associate with a different "desktop"/screen? I heard that VNC on linux has an option to pick desktop like :1 or :2 on the end of it. I haven't tested it though and am not entirely sure what you are referring to 'cos I haven't tried much re multiple monitors

Comment: @barlop I repeat: I am looking for VGA text console, not any GUI.

Comment: @pbies  Is the Terminal  that you are running the SSH client from, in VGA text mode?    Also I did run into the idea that you could try these lines in your sshd_config file `AcceptEnv TERM `  and `PermitTTY vt100` and then restart sshd. 
`sudo systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: @barlop No, the terminal is purely directly from the hardware/OS, it is not an SSH session. It is VGA.

Comment: @pbies how can it be possible for SSH to do such a thing.. SSH shows a console.. Whereas the VGA or HDMI output is what the screen shows which is far broader than simply a console session. And the display protocol, VGA or HDMI, isn't aware of what it's showing, whether it's a console or a BIOS screen or what. I can't see how what you are looking for can even possibly be possible

Comment: @barlop And that's why I am asking how to see the original screen of the computer. No worries, maybe someone else will know.

Comment: @pbies  there would be  a hardware  adaptor that broadcasts it but it's nothing to do with ssh!!!

Comment: @barlop But SSH can connect to tmux or screen which could gain access to tty0. Thank for trying to help.

Comment: @pbies screen output is pixels, it could show a picture of an apple, you won't see it on SSH!  Even if there's no GUI being displayed on the pi at that particular time, The screen is pixels.

Comment: @barlop Thank for trying to help.

Comment: @pbies look suppose you have this magical SSH to VGA thing going on and it were to a machine running DOS 6.22.   Windows 3.1 was an addon program to DOS 6.22, just an application that could be run from the command line. Suppose somebody would run it. What do you think you'd see on your SSH side? Windows?! That wouldn't be an SSH session. That's a demonstrartion of why what you ask for is impossible. And what you really would require would be an HDMI trarnsmitter device, nothing to with SSH!

Comment: @barlop I don't understand what you are talking about.